# Syntax issues: Ternary and loop inside return statement

Tags: java, loops, return, syntax-error, ternary-operator

I'm having some problems with Java syntax. I tried to write a prime-check, and that works just fine

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        boolean out;
        if (n < 2)
            out = false;
        else if (n == 2)
            out = true;
        else if (n % 2 == 0)
            out = false;
        else {
            double sqrtN = Math.sqrt(n);
            for (int i = 3; ; i += 2) {
                if (i > sqrtN)
                    return out = true;
                else if (n % i == 0)
                    return out = false;
            }
        }
        return out; 
}
```

Now I wanted to write this more concise: Get rid of the variable declaration `out`and use `ternary` instead `if`. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static boolean isP(int n) {
        return
            (n < 2) ? false :
            (n == 2) ? true :
            (n % 2 == 0) ? false : {
            double sqrtN = Math.sqrt(n);
            for (int i = 3; ; i += 2) 
                if (i > sqrtN) 
                    return true;
                else if (n % i == 0)
                    return false;
            }
}
```

I don't know what to do with the block statement

```
                {
                double sqrtN = Math.sqrt(n);
                for (int i = 3; ; i += 2) 
                    if (i > sqrtN) 
                        return true;
                    else if (n % i == 0)
                        return false;
                }
```

Can I even incorporate this after `:`? And ternary inside a loop is nonsense/not possible anyway, if I'm not missing something here, so I used `if/else` there.

Then the outmost return obviously lacks a semicolon and I don't know where to fit it.

Hope my intention gets across, so how can I get my second solution get to work? And have you further improvements/suggestions to me how to write this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a succession of 4 ternary operators like you suggest is not such a good idea because it becomes a bit hard to read. If what you are worried about is the number of lines of code you can make you method shorter with:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
  if (n == 2) return true;
  if (n < 2 || n % 2 == 0) return false;

  double sqrtN = Math.sqrt(n);
  for (int i = 3; i <= sqrtN; i += 2) {
    if (n % i == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm used to defining constants that would be otherwise recomputed with each iteration in a recursive function. That was my also my reasoning behind `sqrtN`. But in loops that is completely unnecessary, rigth? So I would just write `Math.sqrt(n)` directly in the loop as the predicate like `for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 2)` and it would be only computed once?

Comment: Your out variable is of no use and makes no difference performance wide. I am unsure about sqrt: it will be calculated at each iteration in interpreted mode - once the JIT kicks in it will probably cache the value but I haven't tested. In any case sqrt is probably only costing a few nanoseconds so unless your prime number is huge it won't make much difference.

Comment: Thanks, it's not that I really cared for performance in that case. Just curious about the evaluation model.